# Conexion a base de datos gratuita nunca termina de cargar

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando practicar sql con un host gratuito, pero aunque he puesto correctamente todos los datos de conexion, el tiempo de demora para conectar parece ser demasiado y mi localhost me tira el siguiente mensaje:
"Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Expiró el tiempo de conexión in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP Y SQL/practice/press.php on line 30"

Quiero saber si es un error mio, o es que por ser gratuito el hosting la conexion a la base de datos es muy lenta y php la paraliza...cabe mencionar que eto no me pasa cuando practico en el local, donde todo funciona perfectamente

Comment: puedes poner el codigo del archivo `press.php`, aproximadamente unas lineas antes y despues de la 30?

Comment: $MARIA = mysqli_connect('sql202.byethost.com', 'b24_22884300', 'clave', 'b24_22884300_press2') ;

Comment: no tendrá que ver con el puerto?????? revisando en mi configuracion de panel veo que el puerto es: 3306

Comment: en el primer campo del metodo MYSQL_CONECT puse el nombre del servidor de la base de datos (MySQL host name)...  Porque cuando pongo el nombre de mi hosting me tira error